# What is the word for the joy felt when a favour offered is subsequently not needed?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a feeling that I get when I have earned "Brownie Points" for offering to do something for someone but the offer gets turned down for some reason before I need to actually do it. All the reward for none of the effort.

Comment: I was tempted to say relief but I think you are looking for something more than that.

Comment: Assassin's Creed Wiki, Juan Borgia the Elder: Final words of Ezio: *And now you pay for it.* [Il piacere immeritato si consuma da sé](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Juan_Borgia_the_Elder) (Pleasure unearned consumes itself).

Comment: I feel like there should be some German word for this, like how they have *schadenfreude*.

Comment: @simchona: you'd think so, but no such word comes to my mind (I'm a native German speaker).

Comment: @Joachim: Good to know.

Comment: You are asking for a word that describes "*this feeling of joy*". Joy is joy and we say joy regardless if it was caused by not getting caught or by getting caught, performing some task or not performing it, sleeping or running, etc... If you are looking for any term that would describe the situation please reword the question (same if you are looking for something else).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a word that encapsulates all of that, but here are a couple of suggestions, depending on the situation. More than likely, an idiomatic phrase will best suit.

1) **off the hook**: addresses the relief, though it doesn't full capture the credit (or brownie points)

2) **absolved**: free of duty or obligation. The downside here is the connotation of forgiven sin--not quite what we're after.

3) **got/gave a free pass**: with enough context, this could work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there exists a single word to describe the feeling you're describing, as it's actually two feelings being experienced simultaneously.

The first is **relief** (*oh good, I don't have to lend him money after all*), and the second is **self-righteousness** (*but wasn't that great of me to offer?*).

We're complex creatures, human beings. More often than not, one word doesn't suffice.